# confuse about prototype object and Object.getPrototypeOf()

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS. I'm reading a javascript book and get confused with the concept of prototype. The book says

**JavaScript objects have a link to another object, known as the prototype, from which they inherit properties and methods.Object is the prototype for most objects, but it also provides some methods that are used directly, rather than through inheritance and below is an example:**

[image]

```
let hat = {
    name: "Hat",
    price: 100,
    getPriceIncTax() {
        return Number(this.price) * 1.2;
    }
};

let hatPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(hat);
```

I'm confused, since `Object` is the prototype of `hat`, so when we try to get the prototype of `hat`, isn't that the prototype is just the `Object` itself? why we still need to get it like:

`let hatPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(hat);`

isn't that just as simple as :

`let hatPrototype = Object`?

Comment: It’s close – `Object.prototype` – but you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf` on something you don’t already know the prototype of, like how `+` is a useful operator even though `2 + 2` can be as simple as `4`.

Comment: Consider `Object.getPrototypeOf(document.getElementById("someid"));`

Comment: @Barmar so does `hat` object inherits from `Object` or `Object.prototype`?

Comment: @secondimage You can find out by running `Object.getPrototypeOf(hat) == Object` and `Object.getPrototypeOf(hat) == Object.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

A prototype is just another object that is used as a fallback source of properties and methods and all objects in javascript derive from "Object.prototype". As you know, "Object.getPrototypeOf" returns the prototype of an object, because you didn't give your "hat" object a prototype, it's prototype will derive from "Object.prototype" by default, if you want to give your "hat" object a prototype, you can use "Object.create" like this.

```
let hatPrototype = {
  getprice: function getPriceIncTax() {
        return Number(this.price) * 1.2;
    }
}

let hat = Object.create(hatPrototype);
hat.price = 100;
hat.name = "hat";

console.log(hat.getprice()); // returns 120
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(hat) == hatPrototype); // returns true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(hatPrototype) == Object.prototype); // returns true
```

Comment: so does `hat` object inherits from `Object` or `Object.prototype`?

Comment: @secondimage It inherits from `hatPrototype`, which inherits from `Object`.

Comment: "*all objects in javascript derive from "Object.prototype"*" - not exactly, no.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `getPrototypeOf` doesn't have that many usecases. Usually you do not care about the prototype chain of a certain object, and if you do, you are usually *debugging* and then you can find these information in your debugger.